# Select Multiple Dates in one calendar control with different SelectedBackgroundColor

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I want to make a calendar like this:

[image: http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/7747/60na.png]

The main idea is to select with diferent days each day with some color selected in a radiobutton. Radiobuttons piece of code is done and works fine but, i have not idea how to select days in one color, because MultipleRange select mode, each time clear the days selected...

I'm working with styles but is so complicated... 
This is the style for CalendarD

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ItemText}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ItemBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="CalendarButtonStyle" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Type CalendarButton}}"/>-->
    <!--<Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{DynamicResource  CalendarDayButtonStyleOriginal}" />
    <Setter Property="CalendarItemStyle" Value="{DynamicResource  CalendarItemStyle}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DayTitleTemplate, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CalendarItem}}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Foreground="{DynamicResource ItemText}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="{DynamicResource DefaultFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="PART_Root">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="132" Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1,-1,-1,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

this is the style for CalendarDayButton

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton"
     x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyleOriginal">        
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
      Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
      Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
      Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
      Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
      Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="0.5"
                               Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="0.5"
                               Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="0"
                               Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To=".35"
                               Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To=".75"
                               Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                             Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                             Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Active" />
                            <VisualState Name="Inactive">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                              To="#FF777777" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="RegularDay" />
                            <VisualState Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="1"
                               Duration="0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                              To="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="NormalDay" />
                            <VisualState Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="Blackout"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To=".2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground"
                 RadiusX="1"
                 RadiusY="1"
                 Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground"
                 RadiusX="1"
                 RadiusY="1"
                 Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground"
                 RadiusX="1"
                 RadiusY="1"
                 Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="5,1,5,1">
                        <TextElement.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF333333" />
                        </TextElement.Foreground>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <Path x:Name="Blackout"
            Opacity="0"
            Margin="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Fill="#FF000000"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,
              11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,
              11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,
              13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,
              17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,
              17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,
              14.042364 z" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                 IsHitTestVisible="false"
                 RadiusX="1"
                 RadiusY="1">
                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the DynamicResources for the Background

```
<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">Crimson</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
```

this is the codebehind:

```
cal = new Calendar();
cal.Name = "MonthlyCalendar";
cal.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Month;
cal.SelectionMode = CalendarSelectionMode.MultipleRange;
cal.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["CalendarStyle"];
```

any help??

Comment: How far have you gotten on your own?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i'm able to change calandardaybuttons backgrownd but globally, not for each range of days...